# Calculate the sum in an loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm currently working on a rails project, I'm kinda newbie in this language. 
Using Devise, I want to have the sum of the sign_in_count and display it.

My sign_in_count is an integer and have a default value at 0, incrementing every time the user sign in.

here's what I've tried so far :

```
count_sign_in = 0

@users.each do |user|
  count_sign_in << user.sign_in_count 
end
```

But as you can imagine, it doesn't work ... 
And I want to have the sum per week and per month if that's possible.

Any help ? 
Many thanks.

Comment: you should use count_sign_in = [] array

Comment: _"I'm kinda newbie in this language"_ – it might come as a surprise, but in Ruby we use `+` to add integers ;-)

Answer (score 3):

I'd use a single SQL query

```
User.sum(:sign_in_count)
```

Comment: Indeed, pretty efficient. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

correct your code:

```
count_sign_in = 0

@users.each do |user|
  count_sign_in += user.sign_in_count # similar to count_sign_in = count_sign_in + user.sign_in_count
end
```

**Note:** `count_sign_in` is not an array, to push element in array we use `<<` in ruby

Answer (score 0):

As already answered above, the easiest way to do this is to use an sql aggregation.

```
User.sum(:sign_in_count)
```

You also perform a sum on a collection of object. In this case an #each iteration  is not the optimale as it require an extra locale variable. The Enumerable module provides a bunch of useful methods like `sum`

```
@users.sum { |user| user.sign_in_count }
```

It can also be written shorten using a symbol to proc

```
@users.sum(&:sign_in_count)
```